# PHP PDO prepared query refuses to execute properly - escaping problem?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a problem with a query prepared in PHP with PDO.  The code:

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=127.0.0.1",$username,$password);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = $link->prepare("SELECT locality_name FROM :passedday GROUP BY locality_name ORDER BY locality_name DESC");
$query->bindParam(":passedday",$day); //Where day is, well, a day passed to the script elsewhere
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
$link = null;
//Do things with the $result.
```

The error message I am getting is:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''05_26_09' GROUP BY locality_name ORDER BY locality_name DESC' at line 1

When I execute the query on the server directly, it returns the appropriate result set without any problem.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

TIA.

Edit:

`$day` is passed as a GET argument.  So, `http://127.0.0.1/day.php?day=05_26_09` leads to `$day = $_GET['day'];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `05_26_09` is supposed to bet the table's name, then I guess you've an escaping problem. Is your local operating system different from the live server?

I don't think you can use `bindValue()`/`bindParam()` for something else than values (eg. table name, field name). So I'm a bit suprised, that it works on your local system.

Comment: Just discovered that on Google.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PDO uses mysql's C-API for prepared statements.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-prepare.html says:

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. [...] However, they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names)

As a rule of thumb I use: "if you can't wrap it in single-quotes in an ad-hoc query string you can't parametrize it in a prepared statement"